# Can you create multiple Customers via a single call to the REST based endpoint?

Tags: acumatica

A customer is trying to load thousands of customers via the Acumatica REST API (18.200.001), they are submitting one at a time and it is taking many hours to complete. Is it possible/helpful to be able to submit them in batches and reduce the traffic/overhead?

Comment: may i ask why not use import scenario ?

Comment: that may be the final solution, but since they have the web service integration working, they wanted to use it, if they can get it performing..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps take a look at the `InventoryItemImportMultiThreaded` tool on Acumatica's github and modify it for Customer Creation.

[InventoryItemMuliThreaded](https://github.com/Acumatica/InventoryItemImportMultiThreaded)